# Can someone tell me why does Lubuntu does not boot into the Gui and there is no command prompt?

Tags: boot, lubuntu, raspberrypi

I downloaded the Ubuntu server 23.04 32bit on 11/05/2023, so it is the latest version and used the raspberry PI imager software to write the MicroSD card. I followed the instructions on your website "How to install Ubuntu on the Raspberry PI". Everything went according to the instructions and then I installed the Lubuntu-desktop and now it stops at [   73.507889] cloud-init[918]: Cloud-init v. 23.1.2-0ubuntu0~23.04.1 finished at Thu, 11 May 2023 14:34:09 +0000. Datasource DataSourceNoCloud [seed=/dev/mmcblk0p1] [dsmode=local]. Up 73.48 seconds and the cursor is just flashing.

Comment: How did you install the Lubuntu desktop?

Comment: There are a number of differences between the *armhf* or *arm64* r.pi server installs and the *amd64* the Lubuntu team packages `lubuntu-desktop` for. A tool that was really useful (*a few years ago anyway*) was https://github.com/wimpysworld/desktopify which lists some of the required tasks to make a r.pi Desktop system...  Your issue maybe `sddm` related though so you could *switch* that out (ie. try a different DM) but sorry my knowledge here is rather dated.

Comment: I used the command sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop as per the instructions.

Comment: What instructions?  I'm not aware of any.